# How do I add images to results of this JQueryUI autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, templates

This is the plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default

Before, I used [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), and it had image support, but this was depreciated and resulted into the jqueryui plugin above.

There aren't any demos or sample code on how to add images using the new plugin.

I want to add images next to the result, like Facebook friends-style.

Answer (score 2):

The [Custom Data and Display](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) demo shows you how:

```
$(selector).autocomplete({ /* ... */ })
    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        /* Custom rendering code here */
    };
```

Hit the "view source" link on the Custom Data demo page for a full example.